# Is there any way to add a widget above the parent(Layout)?

Tags: python, layout, kivy, kivy-language

Hey i recently started with python / kivy programming.
I have a basic question which can not be solved with the documentation i found.

I wanna add a self defined function (InitiateGraph) above my root (ScreenLayout).
Within this function i am plotting a graph with matplotlib, which is generated with the call of the app. It should look like this:

```
_ _  _ _  _ _  _ _  _ _  _ _  _ _  _ _  _ _  _ _  _ _  _ _  _ _  _ _  
|here should be the plotted graph from InitiateGraph|  
_ _  _ _  _ _  _ _  _ _  _ _  _ _  _ _  _ _  _ _  _ _  _ _  _ _  _ _  
_ _  _ _  _ _  _ _  _ _  _ _  _ _  _ _  _ _  _ _  _ _  _ _  _ _  _ _  
|  here should follow the GridLayout (ScreenLayout)   |  
_ _  _ _  _ _  _ _  _ _  _ _  _ _  _ _  _ _  _ _  _ _  _ _  _ _  _ _
```

Currently the two blocks are reversed.
Please see following minimalistic example.

*Python-code:*

```
class ScreenLayout(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ScreenLayout, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.add_widget(self.InitiateGraph())

    def InitiateGraph(self):
        ...

class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return ScreenLayout()

Test = TestApp()
Test.run()
```

*Kivy-code:*

```
<ScreenLayout>:
    rows: 3
    BoxLayout:
    BoxLayout:
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.

You could use the `index` argument to `add_widget` to put the widget at a specific position in the children of your ScreenLayout. But that's rarely the good way, as it easily breaks when you update the layout for other reasons.

A better way is to use a container widget, with an id, so you can easily refer to it and add your widget inside it.

```
<ScreenLayout>:
    rows: 3
    BoxLayout:
        id: graph_container
    BoxLayout:
    BoxLayout:
```

then

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ScreenLayout, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.ids.graph_container.add_widget(self.InitiateGraph())
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, that's exactly what I was looking for :D

Comment: Great, can you mark the answer as accepted then? so it's easier for other people looking for the same thing to see it :).

Comment: Oh yeah sure thing :D have to get comfortable how things are done on the website ^^